# how to add value labels on a matplotlib bar chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've created function for calculating average for delay and over achieving 
and I want to display labels on top of each Value negative and positive

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(xavg_John,yavg_John),(xavg_Dan,yavg_Dan),(xavg_Max,yavg_Max),(xavg_Ann,yavg_Ann),(xavg_Robert,yavg_Robert)],
columns= ["Average Day Delay", "Average Day Over Achive"], index=["John","Dan","Max","Ann","Robert"])
df["Average Day Delay"] = -df["Average Day Delay"]
df.plot(kind="bar",stacked= True);`
```

My current result:
[image]

Desired result:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52012462/is-it-possible-to-put-the-plt-yticks-between-the-horizontal-bars) is of relevance to you. You just have to tweak the code from horizontal bars to vertical bars